# Modify groovy method call with if statement

Tags: if-statement, groovy

I want to have a method call where `if !row[connected].equals("")`

then

```
Event(id: "event_${row[eventid]}", externalId: "event_${row[eventid]}", connected: row[connected]){
```

but `if row[connected].equals("")`

then

```
Event(id: "event_${row[eventid]}", externalId: "event_${row[eventid]}"){
```

I don't want to copy the code twice in an if else statement because there is a ton of code inside the brace of the Event method

Can i do this simply with dollar signs for example so that the call will still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method calls with named arguments in Groovy are simply passing a `Map` to the method, so you could say

```
def eventParams = [
  id: "event_${row[eventid]}", externalId: "event_${row[eventid]}"
]
if(row[connected]) { // empty string is Groovy-false, non-empty is true
  eventParams.connected = row[connected]
}

Event(eventParams)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or a cheeky one-liner:

```
Event( [ id        : "event_${row[eventid]}", 
         externalId: "event_${row[eventid]}" ] << 
           row[connected] == '' ? [:] : [ connected: row[connected] ] )
```

Comment: pretty cool, though won't use for purposes of someone understanding my code in the future haha